# Notification inside app using flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey guys I need help I want to implement notifications inside the app using firebase not the any push notifications in notification tray, just like in app notifications here in the pic you can see, just like this alerts
And this alert contain all the necessary notification from app

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize firebase it will let you specified what you want to do when the notification came. You just put that message (title  body whatsoever)in your storage or db and display via that alert page.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');
  if (message.notification != null) {
    //your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: So It like suppose when application is on background and someone send text, or subscribe to anything. The notification should be displayed and I know it will be implemented through FCM but when user click on Notification from tray. It should land him into the app and that app contains the notification panel or bar or tab etc. It contains all the notifications of the app. Just like facebook app notification. So the method which you suggested would this help me to achieve this kind of sceneario?

Comment: I see, you want when the user tap the notification outside the app, the app will open the notification page, right ?

Comment: not the notification page just open the app. But that notification should be displayed in alert panel too.

Comment: use onBackgroundMessage. see this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages
after you received the notification. store it somewhere in you application storage.